# Best way to save huge text in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-resources

So I was in need of a container to save a lot of dialogue for my apps(branching dialogue), I was thinking about using string value XML but I'm still not quite sure since I have a lot of text and need some kind of tag/attribute to do the branching, 
can I have another value XML that only contain the dialogue text? or should I use SQLite database?
or are there any method best used for my case that I could learn?

Newbie here would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if the text is **dynamic** and will change by time you should consider receiving it from API

if it's **static** and won't change you could store it in the string xml file
you can''t store it in the local sql lite cause all data will be lost if the user clear the cache from settings

Answer (score 0):

Messaging apps are mostly using sqlite databases.
Simply saving message with id and parent id is sufficient to restore branching dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Xml parsing is a slow process plus adding overhead to write is to file storage and read it as it grows big will hurt your app performance, do consider doing multithreading for avoiding ANR and also Roomdb is best choice to store persistent database, learn more from

[Guide to Room db](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Twitter-Persistence-With-Room)